# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-23}]$: A uniquely written set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers

I suspect that

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-23}] \implies \forall~z=\sqrt{23b+a}~e^{i\arctan{\frac{23b}{a}}},~\text{where $z$ is uniquely written}~\forall~z\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-23}]$

[image]

Comment: In polar form I reason that (i) is so because no two distances are the same for any combination of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I think that worrying about polar form is a mistake here, and won't take you anywhere.

Comment: You're thinking too much about complex analysis.  No need to worry about polar form.

Comment: @Brian I mean, my reasoning is well founded, no?

Comment: Your set is simply all complex numbers of the form $a + bi\sqrt{23}$ where $a, b$ are integers.  Your reasoning is not really useful for these problems.

Comment: @Brian Oh, no, I said "[t]ypical" because my question got downvoted.

Comment: I agree with you though. My reasoning isn't "useful" for "these problems," but I feel it is always necessary to mesh distant concepts to see things anew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a+b\sqrt{-23}=a'+b'\sqrt{-23}\Rightarrow (a-a')+(b-b')\sqrt{-23}=0\Rightarrow a=a',\ b=b'$.

Comment: So simple... Thank you Federica Maggioni.

Comment: How do you verify (iii)? I meant (iii) not (ii), but I see now.

Comment: @Trancot Suppose $2+\sqrt{-23}=3(a+b\sqrt{-23})$. Hence $2+\sqrt{-23}=3a+3b\sqrt{-23}$, and by unicity $2=3a$ and $1=3b$, whith no solutions in integers

Comment: Yes, I have that sketched out just here. Thank you again Federica Maggioni.